# Why are player numbers not in a different column?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I have created a script that collects the information on a website and puts it on a script. I'm on my process to become acquainted with python **scraping** and I would like some help as I would like to player numbers to be on a different column

```
# import libraries

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook

# Workbook is created
wb = Workbook()

# add_sheet is used to create sheet.
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

#send request

#url = 'http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-11/1i/sant-ildefons-ue-b/1i/lhospitalet-centre-esports-c'

url = 'https://www.fcf.cat/acta/2422183'

page = requests.get(url,timeout=5, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

#read acta

#acta_text = []
#acta_text_element = soup.find_all(class_='acta-table')

#for item in acta_text_element:
#    acta_text.append(item.text)
i = 0
acta = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
   values = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') ]
   print(values)
   acta.append(values)
   i = 1 + i
   sheet1.write(i,0,values)

wb.save('xlwt example.xls')

print(acta)
```

Thanks,

Comment: I would recommend creating another empty array, appending to that array the value you want in another column, then transforming the arrays into a pandas dataframe. If it looks good, save the dataframe as an excel file.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: I would like that each value is in a different column. The player numbers and names are appended on the same cell. I would like to have separate columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to consider:

- You can separate the first element in the list by using `values[0]` then use `values[1:]` for the remaining items
- Use `isnumeric` to check if a string value is a number

Try this code:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
   values = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td') ]
   print(values)
   acta.append(values)
   i = 1 + i
   if len(values) and values[0].isnumeric():  # if first element is number
       sheet1.write(i,0,values[0])  # number in column 1
       sheet1.write(i,1,values[1:])  # rest of list in column 2
   else:
       sheet1.write(i,0,values)  # all values in column 1
```

Excel output (truncated)

[image: Excel]

Comment: Please accept an answer to remove this post from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To take the team on the left, for example, try this:

```
tables = soup.select('table')
players = []
columns = ["Player","Shirt"]
titulars = [item for item in tables[1].text.strip().split('\n') if len(item)>0] 
#tables[1] is where the data for the first team is; the other team is in tables[8]

for num, name in zip(titulars[2::2],titulars[1::2]):
    player = []
    player.extend((num,name))    
    players.append(player)
pd.DataFrame(players,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
    Player                        Shirt
0   TORNER ENCINAS, GONZALO     1
1   MACHUCA LOVERA, OSMAR SILVESTRE     3
2   JARA MARTIN, BLAI   4
3   AGUILAR LUQUE, DANIEL   5
4   FONT MURILLO, JOAQUIN   6
5   MARTÍNEZ ELVIR, RICHARD ADRIAN  7
6   MARQUEZ RODRIGUEZ, GERARD   8
7   PATUEL BATLLE, GERARD   10
8   EL MAHI ZAROUALI, BILAL     11
9   JAUME MORERA, ADRIA     14
10  DEL VALLE ESCANCIANO, MARTI     15
```